# NewRelic + Magento1 - how to rewrite Mage::logException in a Magento-way

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to rewrite the original Magento `Mage.app`-Function `logException` so that it'll push catched exceptions to a custom function.

I already changed the default error handler with an early-catching observer, now I want to add my custom logic to the method named above.

Technically I could just edit the original Mage.app-File but I figure that I don't really want to do this.

So the question is, do I rather "deal with it" or rewrite all existing functionality inside my (huge custom, but team maintained) to another custom function that behaves like `logException`?

What possibilities does a Magento Developer have when trying to rewrite those methods declared inside `Mage.php`?

Comment: I think there is no good way to override Mage.php. But, if you want to extend the native logs, you should look the extension ProxiBlue_NewRelic for example. The key point is here : https://github.com/ProxiBlue/NewRelic/blob/6973346ccecde46eb85103a8166926669211b0b4/app/code/community/ProxiBlue/NewRelic/etc/config.xml#L111
They override the node <log><core><writer_model>